# Class for minizing database interaction?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

I'm doing a Data Science project in Python in which many functions and objects have been refactored into classes. One of these classes is the `Universe()` which contains all *names and attributes* in our database. As you can imagine, it's huge (takes well over 5 minutes to load) and it's imported in at least two other classes (thus slowing the other class instantiations down considerably).

I'd like to make it so that in the running kernel this class is only instantiated once even when imported from other classes (thus minimizing Database interaction). I've thought of using `static` classes but from what I've read python developers absolutely hate static classes and consider it non-pythonic.

Are there any other more pythonic solutions to this problem? How would you define a class that encapsulates data and minimizes Database interaction for all other classes that use it?

Comment: It's two classes, base and derived. Base imports, aggregates into pandas DataFrame. Derived computes metrics and aggregates into DF. As some data is stored outside the DF as well and the rest of the code is dependent on the output being a DF I'd like for it to stay as class (I need access to rows as well as columns and some DF specific methods).

Comment: Each class is in its own module. Do you mean that code after the class definition will only use the one instance? On the matter of dependent modules (of which there are three), how would you rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and instantiate a class in its own module, at module level. That module will only be imported once, and thus the class is only instantiated once.

Example:

file: `uni.py`:

```
class _Universe:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.get_database_info()

    def get_database_info(self):
        print('db info')


Universe = _Universe()
```

file: `unia.py`:

```
import unib
from uni import Universe
```

file: `unib.py`:

```
from uni import Universe
```

Executing file `unia.py` suggest the `Universe` class is imported twice, but looking at the output (from the print functions), you'll see instantiating this happens once: Python is smart enough to re-use the already imported module:

`python unia.py`:

output:

```
init
db info
```

---

Note that I'm using `_Universe`, so the class instance can be called `Universe`, to ease code changes

If you have code where `Universe()` is instantiated (outside the `uni` module), you could cheat somewhat and add the `__call__()` method to `_Universe`. Though it'd be better and clearer to rewrite those little bits of code from e.g. `universe = Universe()` to `Universe`:

```
class _Universe:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.get_database_info()

    def get_database_info(self):
        print('db info')

    def __call__(self):
        return self
```

and now in e.g. `unia.py`, you could have:

```
import unib
from uni import Universe

universe = Universe()
```

without repercussions.
Since that, however, may lead to confusion (why "instantiate" an instance?), it's better not to. Perhaps just for an initial quick test and timing of results.